# How can I read and create foxpro files on linux?

Tags: linux, mono, odbc, foxpro, visual-foxpro

My C# / Mono application needs to run on linux.  I must have the ability to dump a foxpro dbf and to create a new foxpro dbf.

Any suggestions for either:
1) odbc for linux designed for Foxpro?
or
2) a utility to read and create Foxpro files?

In many cases I have index (CDX) files and and in a limited set I also have the memo (FPT) files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The entire process must run on the linux box so I can not connect to a windows server.  I could not find odbc or any open source solution.

The best solution I found was www.codebase.com.  I purchased Codebase for Linux, a library that will do everything I need and more.

Answer (score 0):

I've used [DBI:XBase](http://search.cpan.org/~janpaz/DBD-XBase-1.03/lib/DBD/XBase.pm) in the past to migrate FoxPro tables into MySQL. I don't think it can handle the memo (fpt) though.

Answer (score 0):

If you use SAMBA and Ubuntu 13.04 or some other version Visual Foxpro or FoxPro dbf/fpt reads will work great.